# CentOS 7 installation issue due to unsupported virtualization by my CPU

Tags: windows-7, vmware, centos-7

I need to Install CentOS 7 on my computer for preparation of my RHCSA/RHCE 7 exams.

I have a laptop that has a 64 bit CPU (with 64 bit Windows 7 installed on it), but the CPU does not support virtualization (Intel VT-x z : I checked it from BIOS, too), hence my attempts to install CentOS 7 x86-64 on VMware have failed. Is there any workaround to this problem so that I can install it on my computer(not necessarily on VMware)?

Laptop specs: CPU - Pentium Dual core CPU T4400 2.20 GHz / 2GB RAM

Two Alternatives I think that can work, but I'm not sure if they will:

- One thing that occurred to me is that I can install CentOS 7 as a dual boot besides my Windows 7 Host. Will this work or will there still be complications that I should look at before trying it?
- Another Alternative I thought of is to Install Fedora 20 (32-bit) on VMware.  Does it have systemd/systemsctl features like the new Red Hat 7? I don't have any knowledge about Fedora but I know it's a Red Hat like OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dualbooting seems the best option to use linux on your pc considering that your computer only has 2 gb of RAM and does not support virtualization.

If you want to learn about RedHat linux you can use Centos and Fedora. RedHat Enterprise Linux 7 introduced systemd while 
Fedora started using systemd long before RHEL did. Centos 7 is equivalent to RHEL7.

Answer (score 2):

if your CPU doesnt support virtualization, then thats just it, you cant VIRTUALIZE it. But as you said, you can install it beside your win7 installation.

i would run the live cd and mess around before installing it, thats one way you can see if any errors occur.